# strange objective c error while using base64

Tags: objective-c

I just tried out the following code segment and im having an error :-

```
#import "JSONKit.h"
#import "Base64.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main() { 
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; [dict setObject:(id)@"value" forKey:(id)@"key"];

for(id key in dict) NSLog(@"%@\t%@\n", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);

[Base64 initialize]; 
NSData *jsonstr = [dict JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:nil]; 
NSString *val = [Base64 encode: jsonstr]; 
NSLog(@"%@\n", val);

return 0; 
}
```

The error I got is :-

```
test.m: In function ‘main’:
test.m:13: warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing ‘struct NSString *’, expected ‘struct NSData *’
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Base64", referenced from:
      __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in cc23xlpr.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In order to remove the warning, I changed a line to :-

```
NSData *jsonstr = (NSData *)[dict JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:nil];
```

However, the error remains -- being new to objective-C I find the error quite cryptic, could someone help me understand the source of the problem/a solution to the same?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that `[dict JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:nil]` method return the string and if you want to serialize that string into NSData you should do follow:

```
[Base64 initialize]; 
NSString *jsonStr = [dict JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:nil]; 
NSData *jsonstrData = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *val = [Base64 encode: jsonstrData]; 
NSLog(@"%@\n", val);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- but now i get a slightly different error => https://gist.github.com/56381c2e6dd7c18d7501